# Send multiple emails using PHP

Tags: php, email

I working on a project in which i need to develop a functionality to send multiple emails to client with one click and i am adding customer id in one text box separating them with comma.
Please tell me how to do this problematically. Your advice

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ... please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and read about [how to ask a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) ... you have showed very little effort here - something the community won't like and likely yo get this question closed. A simple search in your favourite search engine would be a good start !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php.net's [mail function page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) explains this well

Answer (score 3):

```
 <?php
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
 ?>
```

if you want to send the user as in db jus replace the $to address from db and place these code in loop.

Answer (score 1):

to be fair we all had to start somewhere. The problem with using "[vanilla PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)" is that it is almost always used when people send mail as spam. So for 10 years mail servers haven't liked it. There are ways round it but to be brief:

To send Email via a webpage you ***"should"***

- have your mail server [resolve RDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)
- try to avoid cheap/free web hotels as mailserver hosts
- use [PHP PEAR MAIL](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) (this is tricky/odd to install)
- properly [apply the correct headers for the mail in PEAR](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check below link may be help you.

http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail.cfm